# How do I prove that the area of a sphere is the least possible area for a given volume?

Tags: volume, area

Or, why do soap bubbles have the shape of a sphere and not that of unicorns?

What's the math behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fact: the [isoperimetric inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) in higher dimensions follows from the [Brunn-Minkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunn%E2%80%93Minkowski_theorem) inequality.

Second fact: the shape of a bubble depends on the shape that minimize the potential, i.e. maximize the volume for a given area, or (dual problem) minimize the area for a given volume. By using reflections we have that any solution (we do not know in advance that there is a unique solution) is given by a convex shape, and unicorns are not convex bodies.

Comment: Or in more specific reply to OP does the inequality $ 36 \pi\,V^2 \le   A^3 $  also hold good? [ Some sort of iso-areal inequality :) ]

Comment: @Narasimham: yes, it holds. It is equivalent to the Sobolev inequality in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as mentioned also in the linked Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

The maths behind this is a topic called ["Calculus of Variations"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) - I would start there and you could do worse than something like Gelfand's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486414485) on the subject

You want to find the functional which will represent the surface of minimum area. This is a 2-D extension of simpler problems like finding minimal curves. For example, this is one of the ways you can derive the equation of a catenary - the shape that a heavy chain makes hanging from two points under its own weight.